Rough estimation of stroke volume
I wanted to know if you could use PWV in combination with PP to estimate SV (pulse wave velocity, pulse pressure and stroke volume).
My understanding is, the higher the arterial stiffness that is, the higher the pulse wave velocity the lower the arterial compliance and therefore for the same volume change in the arteries the observed blood pressure would be higher.
That means that PP would be roughly similar to the SV divided by C (arterial compliance).
If we rearrange this we can get an estimate of SV by multiplying arterial compliance with pulse pressure, or the other way around, dividing pulse pressure by PWV.
Is this estimate sound and will reflect a somewhat linear relationship in general with stroke volume? is it better than pulse pressure alone? I dont want the specific value of stroke volume i just want a rough somewhat linearly correlated estimate that is better than pulse pressure alone.
Edit
I would probably add the Liljestrand and Zander adjustment, so the equation would end up looking like this:
$$SV ≈ \frac{\text{PP}}{(\text{SBP} + \text{DBP}) \times \text{PWV}}
$$
Edit 2
This is actually interesting and reflects real world physics to some extent, the equation for the radial stress in a thin walled pressure vessel (like an artery) is the hoop stress equation:
$$σ = \frac{\text{P}r}{\text{t}}
$$
Given that we are interested in the  change in the artery radius which would be reflective of the stroke volume, and the arteries behave elastically we have to take into account this to get the strain:
$$σ = E · ϵ
$$
The strain is defined as this, in relation to radius:
$$ϵ =  \frac{Δr} {r_0}
$$
If we substitute everything we obtain:
$$Δr =  \frac{Pr^2} {Et}
$$
The unit $Et$ is the young modulus times the thickness which combined are basically a measure of the stiffness and resistance to deformation of the walls, and therefore conceptually very similar to PWV.
So I think using PWV here could add more information, given this analogy to real world physics.
